# Creating an object.cshtml editor template with MVC and Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am looking to create an editor template for Object.cshtml to change the behavior of the Html.EditorForModel() method. I can't find any example of this using Razor. I have seen [this example](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html) using MVC2 and WebForm view engine but don't know enough about razor to convert it. Even a simple example would be very helpful.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm just going to do the Display template and leave the rest as an exercise for the reader:)

```
@if (Model == null) {
    <text>@ViewData.ModelMetadata.NullDisplayText</text>
} else if (ViewData.TemplateInfo.TemplateDepth > 1) {
    <text>@ViewData.ModelMetadata.SimpleDisplayText</text>
} else {
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    @foreach (var prop in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties.Where(pm => pm.ShowForDisplay && !ViewData.TemplateInfo.Visited(pm))) {
        if (prop.HideSurroundingHtml) {
            <text>@Html.Display(prop.PropertyName)</text>
        } else {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="display-label" style="text-align: right;">
                        @prop.GetDisplayName()
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="display-field">
                        @Html.Display(prop.PropertyName)
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
    </table>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but when I paste this code into my object.cshtml I get "error CS1024: Preprocessor directive expected"

Comment: Doh, your code is correct. I accidentally had #Html.EditorForModel() rather than @Html.EditorForModel(). At least your code is not wasted and will be first seen by many new Razor users in the future.

Comment: I can't even get my Object.cshtml to execute.  I placed it in Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Object.cshtml  Any ideas?

Comment: @Doug You may have the problem I had, when I called DisplayForModel, passing my object, it didn't display anything because the TemplateDepth was greater than 1.  I simply commented out lines 3-4 for now to get it working, but the idea is that when nesting occurs with complex types, they don't render the full ObjectTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

This seem to work for **Editor Template** for bootstrap, please let me know of any improvements

Object.cshtml

```
@if (Model == null)
{
    <text>@ViewData.ModelMetadata.NullDisplayText</text>
}
else if (ViewData.TemplateInfo.TemplateDepth > 1)
{
    <text>@ViewData.ModelMetadata.SimpleDisplayText</text>
}
else
{
    foreach (var prop in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties.Where(pm => pm.ShowForDisplay && !ViewData.TemplateInfo.Visited(pm)))
    {
        if (prop.HideSurroundingHtml)
        {
            <text>@Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName)</text>
        }
        else
        {
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.Label(prop.PropertyName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2", @style = "text-align:right;" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName, null, new { @class = "form-control " })
                    @Html.ValidationMessage(prop.PropertyName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    }
}
```