# Customize not only editor template but the outer html

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, template-engine

In MVC.Net 3 I can customize the way String and other primitive type are render using EditorTemplate.

For instance if I have a `EditorTemplates/String.cshtml`

```
@Html.TextBox("")
```

I get the default rendering. 
Consider the simple model:

```
class Foo
{
   public string Route {get; set; }
}
```

The rendering of the form would yield something like:

```
<div class="editor-label"><label for="Route">Test Route</label></div>
<div class="editor-field">
   <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Test Route field is required." id="Route" name="Route" type="text"> 
   <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Route" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

Here is the question: With the String.chtml I am only able to customize the inner html of the div `editor-field`. How can I also customize the div itself to add css class and others attributes?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a custom `object.cshtml` in your `Shared/EditorTemplates/` folder.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029402/creating-an-object-cshtml-editor-template-with-mvc-and-razor) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029402/creating-an-object-cshtml-editor-template-with-mvc-and-razor)  for some example implementations

Comment: Ok overriding the Object template seems to be the solution. It look to me that the default Object template lake of flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches to customize what you need.

1. Add an editor template for your model object `Foo`. This way cause a coupled connection between template and the model. Every changes in model must be applied on the template.
2. Overwrite the internal Object template by adding Object.cshtm in `Views/ControllerName/EditorTemplates` or `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates`. This is more generic and loosely coulped.

For more information about customizing object template view [this](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html) link.

Edited:

In the `Object.cshtml` you can check for the Foo model and apply the Foo's specific customization.

```
 @if (Model is Foo)
 {
    //specific customization for the Foo
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is where the extension method `EditorFor` is useful. Any markup that you include in your template (e.g. `String.cshmlt`) will be written out if you use `EditorFor`. So you can have this in your template:

```
// you can basically do whatever you want here  
// add some label, span, etc.
<div class="some-class">
    <div class="another-class">
        @Html.TextBox(string.Empty, /* Name suffix */
            ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue /* Initial value */
        )
    </div>
</div>
```

And let the view engine render it by doing:

```
@Html.EditoFor(m=>m.Route)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that imply to use EditorFor for each properties of my model and that is not an option. I would end-up with a highly couple view/model.

Comment: You view and model will not be tightly coupled because you can always swap editorfor with, for example, textboxfor, or any other htmlhelper for that matter. Tightly coupling means that you will not be able to use any htmlhelper with your model.

Comment: No offence but I do not have the same definition of coupling. Coupling means that a change in A force a change in B. For instance when I add a property in my model I need to modify my view to take in account the new property. In contrary if I only use the EditorForModel, the property is automatically taken in consideration. That is what I want to avoid.

Comment: I think we have the same idea, we just gave different examples. So, `EditorFor` is applied to a single property, I think you know that. `EditForModel` is a different thing. If you change something in your model's property how does that affect the template? If you change the template how does that affect the property of your model? I think both of them don't care what others will look like. And so there's no tight coupling there, ain't it?

Comment: ok let me give more precision on what I am doing. I am using EditorForModel(anInstanceOfFoo). If I do that I am not able to change the way each field is render. I get the `div` and I can not add a css class to it. And using the EditorTemplate does not help. Because EditorTemplate only allow you to specify the inner html of the editor-field `div`. Hope I made it more clear

Answer (score 0):

All of the answers posted are valid but may be over-engineering the solution a little. If you are concerned about avoiding tight-coupling, you can just keep the editor template described in von v's answer generic and pass additional parameters to it via the template's `ViewData` collection. For example, if you have a string of additional classes you want to append to the outer div...

```
@if (ViewData.ContainsKey("additionalClasses"))
{
    /* Append classes to div */
}
else 
{
    /* Div without classes */
}
```

Now, you can pass `additionalClasses` in from the main view, like so:

```
@EditorFor(m => m.Route, "MyTemplate", new { additionalClasses = "myclass" })
```